# Mirror formatting spring-data-rest/spring-hateoas in custom controllers

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I used the suggested approach in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365089/spring-hateoas-xml-serialization-for-list-of-resources-built-with-resourceassemb) to return HATEOAS formatted outputs that match those returned by spring-data-rest. It works good, but is there a way to avoid boiler plate code to create entity resource assemblers like the QuestionResourceAssembler in the referenced question, if I only want to add 'self' links using the id to all entities? Perhaps using [ResourceAssemblerSupport](http://javadox.com/org.springframework.hateoas/spring-hateoas/0.16.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/hateoas/mvc/ResourceAssemblerSupport.html)?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to simply use the `Resource` wrapper type:

```
Resource<Person> personResource = new Resource<>(person);
personResource.addLink(…);
personResource.addLink(…);
```

Links can be created either by simply instantiating them (i.e. `new Link("http://localhost/foo", "relation")` or by using the `ControllerLinkBuilder` which allows you to point to Controller methods for obtain a reverse mapping. See [this section](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas#link-builder) of the Readme for details.